# R Studio: Creating a empty list results in an Error: 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Tags: r, list

I am quite new to R and tried to create an empty list (names Input_IMPLEMENTATION) using:

```
Input_IMPLEMENTATION<-vector(mode="list",length=7)
```

However, this resulted in the following error:

```
Error in names(x) <- paste("V", seq_along(x), sep = "") : 
  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

If I use a different name for the list, everything works fine. for example:

```
Input_IMPLEMENTATION_a<-vector(mode="list",length=7)
```

Therefore, I assumed the error occurs as Input_IMPLEMENTATION is allready assigned some value. So I tried `rm(Input_IMPLEMENTATION)` before executing the code, but this did not change anything.

Does anyone have a hint for me, why I get this error?

Comment: Restart R and try again.

Comment: okay...that was easy. Restarting solved the problem...Thanks!